# Can t get my 12V DC compressor working using a 12V battery

Tags: batteries, 12v

I don't know anything about electronics but I can tell that a 12v Battery can normally power a 12v DC compressor (as shown in the picture) unfortunately it doesn't work (but it does when its plug to my car s cigarette lighter socket.)
could you please help me.
In advance thank you.[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't have a high enough capacity, get a 12V battery with a much higher amp-hour rating. We would also need to know how many amps that compressor draws.

Comment: The "23A" on the battery is a size code,  not a current rating. That tiny battery is nowhere near capable of supplying the current that compressor requires.

Answer (score 0):

No, your 23A-size battery has far too high internal resistance/too low current capacity to power your pump.

Your car battery can supply 100-1000 more current, ample to power your pump.